# Execute EXE with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

My company had a legacy Windows Form `VB` application which allowed users to update their Outlook Signature. I have recently re-written that application in `C#` and am now trying to duplicate their distribution technique but am encountering errors.

They created an `ASPX` page which simply contains a `JavaScript` function to execute the EXE, see below:

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<script language="javascript" >
    function todo() {
        //window.open('', '_self', '');
        //window.close();
        var theShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
        var theApp = "S:\\web\\EMS_2013\\EmailSignature1_2013.exe";
        theShell.ShellExecute(theApp, "", "", "open", "1");
        window.opener = ''
        window.close();
    }    
</script>

</head>
<body onload="window.opener='';todo()">
</body>
</html>
```

> How can I convert this functionality to be based on C# instead of VB?  And for starters, how can I get the webpage `JS` function to open the EXE locally in Debug mode?

I only know VB to the extent that I can reverse engineer these old applications and we are trying to move away from VB so ideally this simple app gets converted as well.

In my research I have struggled to find explanations of how to do this, because the consensus is that security settings prevent web browsers from running an EXE on the client machine. But this application is doing it.

I have created a simple .NET web application and recreated the HTML / Javascript side, but I cannot get it to execute the `EXE` even locally, and the `VB` application was deployed to an IIS server.

> I'm not sure how to move forward... Should I be able to execute the EXE in debug mode from the web browser before trying to deploy to my IIS server? Is there are alternate technique which will allow me to run the EXE for users without them receiving any confirmation prompts?

Here is the content of the `VB` application's `web.config` file, I'm not literate enough to understand what is going on in there

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- 
    Note: As an alternative to hand editing this file you can use the 
    web admin tool to configure settings for your application. Use
    the Website->Asp.Net Configuration option in Visual Studio.
    A full list of settings and comments can be found in 
    machine.config.comments usually located in 
    \Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework\v2.x\Config 
-->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.extensions" type="System.Web.Configuration.SystemWebExtensionsSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <sectionGroup name="scripting" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
        <section name="scriptResourceHandler" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingScriptResourceHandlerSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        <sectionGroup name="webServices" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingWebServicesSectionGroup, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
          <section name="jsonSerialization" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingJsonSerializationSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="Everywhere"/>
          <section name="profileService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingProfileServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <section name="authenticationService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingAuthenticationServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
          <section name="roleService" type="System.Web.Configuration.ScriptingRoleServiceSection, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" allowDefinition="MachineToApplication"/>
        </sectionGroup>
      </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings/>
  <system.web>
    <!-- 
            Set compilation debug="true" to insert debugging 
            symbols into the compiled page. Because this 
            affects performance, set this value to true only 
            during development.

            Visual Basic options:
            Set strict="true" to disallow all data type conversions 
            where data loss can occur. 
            Set explicit="true" to force declaration of all variables.
        -->
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Core, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add assembly="System.Xml.Linq, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
        <add assembly="System.Data.DataSetExtensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <clear/>
        <add namespace="System"/>
        <add namespace="System.Collections"/>
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
        <add namespace="System.Collections.Specialized"/>
        <add namespace="System.Configuration"/>
        <add namespace="System.Text"/>
        <add namespace="System.Text.RegularExpressions"/>
        <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
        <add namespace="System.Xml.Linq"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Caching"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.SessionState"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Security"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Profile"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts"/>
        <add namespace="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls"/>
      </namespaces>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
    <!--
            The <authentication> section enables configuration 
            of the security authentication mode used by 
            ASP.NET to identify an incoming user. 
        -->
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <!--
            The <customErrors> section enables configuration 
            of what to do if/when an unhandled error occurs 
            during the execution of a request. Specifically, 
            it enables developers to configure html error pages 
            to be displayed in place of a error stack trace.

        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="GenericErrorPage.htm">
            <error statusCode="403" redirect="NoAccess.htm" />
            <error statusCode="404" redirect="FileNotFound.htm" />
        </customErrors>
        -->
    <httpHandlers>
      <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpHandlers>
    <httpModules>
      <add name="ScriptModule" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </httpModules>
  </system.web>
  <!-- 
        The system.webServer section is required for running ASP.NET AJAX under Internet
        Information Services 7.0.  It is not necessary for previous version of IIS.
    -->
  <system.codedom>
      <compilers>
        <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4">
          <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
          <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
      </compiler>
        <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4">
          <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v3.5"/>
          <providerOption name="OptionInfer" value="true"/>
          <providerOption name="WarnAsError" value="false"/>
      </compiler>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.webServer>
      <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules>
      <remove name="ScriptModule"/>
      <add name="ScriptModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptModule, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="WebServiceHandlerFactory-Integrated"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactory"/>
      <remove name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices"/>
      <remove name="ScriptResource"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptHandlerFactoryAppServices" verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
      <add name="ScriptResource" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" preCondition="integratedMode" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding appliesTo="v2.0.50727" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Extensions.Design" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-1.1.0.0" newVersion="3.5.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Could be a rule on the browser, saying that this specific url can run this specific executable.

Comment: What you have shown us isn't very clear I'm afraid. The first code snippet only shows Javascript code, not VB (though it does suggest the code behind is VB). are you trying to get this executable to run on the client machine when they open this page?

Comment: Correct, the way I understand it, this `Default.aspx` page sits on an IIS server and when a user navigates to it the webpage pops up, executes the `JS` funciton which runs the `EXE`.  The purpose of this is presumably to avoid the user needing to allow the EXE to run? I'm not sure on the `why` as much as the layman's `how`. The `Default.aspx.vb` which is included with the `ASPX` file contains nothing, see the following:


`Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    
End Class`

Comment: So your app doesn't have any VB code at all, that's just a red herring here. Getting a browser to run an executable on a client computer however is going to be problematic. Any modern browser will do anything it can to stop you running code as it may be malicious. I'm not sure you can do anything that would work consistently.

Comment: var theShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");  this line is only compatible with ie not firefox or chrome.

Comment: classic compatibility issue, that should have been much higher in my testing order. By running in IE i now get a `Permission Denied` error at the `ShellExecute` step. I wonder if this is circumvented in their `web.config` file

Comment: Permission is on the client, not the server. Like I said, most of your question is a red herring - you should not be trying to run an executable with the browser.

Comment: this sounds like an XY problem. what is that .exe doing? and could it be done in javascript, in the browser? (or could the browser maybe do it with a proper plugin or add-on)

Comment: The EXE uses Word Interop to generate the Signature files based on a combination of database values and user input. It also gives a preview prior to clicking the "Generate" button.  The original goal was to make this into a web app but Word Interop isn't recommended to be automated on a Server and generating a Signature with OpenXML was a pain.  I've successfully redirected this Javascript function to our new application so maybe this sticks around a while longer

Answer (score 0):

I found that I can achieve this functionality by executing the EXE from the background C# code, and then I simply close the web page which is created initially.

Web Page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="EmailSignature_EXEC.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<script>
function loaded()
{
    alert("\\\\cmbfs02\\Software\\web\\EmailSignature_WPF\\EmailSignature_WPF.exe");
    window.setTimeout(CloseMe, 500);
}

function CloseMe() 
{
    window.open('', '_self').close();
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="loaded()">
Hello!
    \\\\cmbfs02\\Software\\web\\EmailSignature_WPF\\EmailSignature_WPF.exe
</body>
</html>
```

C# Code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load()
    {
        var applicationPath = "\\\\cmbfs02\\Software\\web\\EmailSignature_WPF\\EmailSignature_WPF.exe";
        Process.Start(applicationPath);
        this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Close", "window.close()", true);
    }
}
```

Now I just need to get this to work when deployed to the server.....

Comment: Process.Start will always launch the process on the server and never on the client. you may be tempted to think it could work as on the development machine, client = server.

Comment: interesting, i just posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47397006/asp-net-on-load-method-not-executing

Do you think that this is my issue? And if so, how else could I run the EXE?