# ASP .NET On_Load method not executing

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, pageload

I am working on a kludge which is working locally but not after I deploy it to our server.

> I have a web page which opens, runs an `EXE` and then closes the web page. Locally this works but after publishing to the server the `EXE` does not run.  I have confirmed that the file path works from the server.

My Web Page code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="EmailSignature_EXEC.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
<script>
function loaded()
{
    window.setTimeout(CloseMe, 500);
}

function CloseMe() 
{
    window.open('', '_self').close();
}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</head>
<body onLoad="loaded()">
Hello!
    \\\\cmbfs02\\Software\\web\\EmailSignature_WPF\\EmailSignature_WPF.exe
</body>
</html>
```

C# Code:

```
using System.Diagnostics;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load()
    {
        var applicationPath = "\\\\cmbfs02\\Software\\web\\EmailSignature_WPF\\EmailSignature_WPF.exe";
        Process.Start(applicationPath);
        this.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Close", "window.close()", true);
    }
}
```

When I browse to my page on `IIS` I see the page appear and close after the `Timeout` but the Application doesn't run. If I copy the `EXE` path into Windows Explorer the application runs, but it does not from the method. Any help appreciated

Comment: Does the account that IIS is running the Application Pool under have the rights to access and execute the file?

Comment: I just updated the App Pool so that it runs as myself (an admin) rather than our service account, same results. Would I get any sort of message indicating failure? I get no feedback at all that the  method was even hit, though again, locally it executes as expected on Page_Load

Comment: when you say that it "runs an exe" - *where* does it run the exe? from the name (WPF), it sounds like it is a UI application. Running that *on the web-server* (which is a service) is not going to work. Are you trying to bring up an exe *on the client* here?

Comment: It runs an EXE which is stored on a shared drive. \\\\cmbfs02\\Software\\web\\EmailSignature_WPF\\EmailSignature_WPF.exe
This exe has been developed and compiled seperately, the EXE works if it were to be 'double clicked' from the server by following the path I specify. 
The end goal is to have a user navigate to the published Website which runs this EXE. Now, for testing, I am navigating to the site from the IIS Server but that would not be the true end use case.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: @gruff but: is this application designed as a server-side headless tool that just does some processing on behalf of a web-server? or is it a client UI that the user expects to interact with? because what you're doing will only work for the first of those. Keep in mind: it isn't the **client desktop** that is running that `Process.Start` - it is your web-server, and more specifically the IIS / app-pool service account. It doesn't *have* a desktop upon which to display a UI.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to launch a UI exe **on the client**, but what you're actually doing is executing it *on the web server*. If that's right, then fundamentally what you're trying to do is just ... not going to work. Ignoring the fact that the implementation would have to be completely different, browsers are explicitly designed **not** to run arbitrary executables from web servers - plus of course it would only work on certain OSes - presumably windows in this case.

A few years ago I might have said "look into ClickOnce for this" - but I have no idea whether that option is still supported or recommended.

Comment: I understand what you mean about Browsers preventing this, but I am rewriting an old VB application we have in C#. The reason for the web browser piece is to mimic a Web App and avoid the "Run / Cancel" window when running the EXE.
The reason for not using a Web App in the first place is that this is an application which generates Outlook Signature files, and the WordInterop COM library will not work when run on a server (Web App)

Comment: @gruff that doesn't change anything; a: the browser doesn't care about your motives, and b: the browser isn't even seeing this right now - everything here is happening *on the server*; all the browser is seeing is a tiny bit of html that closes itself immediately after loading - it *doesn't see* the `Process.Start` - that happens **on the server**

Comment: So is there an alternative to the `Process.Start`?

The original application used this code, and it worked:


`<head runat="server">
<script language="javascript" >
    function todo() {
        //window.open('', '_self', '');
        //window.close();
        var theShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
        var theApp = "S:\\web\\EMS_2013\\EmailSignature1_2013.exe";
        theShell.ShellExecute(theApp, "", "", "open", "1");
        window.opener = ''
        window.close();
    }    
</script>

</head>
<body onload="window.opener='';todo()">
</body>`

Comment: @gruff whatever the alternative is: it won't involve `Page_Load` - that's strictly server-side.  If you can script it via `ActiveXObject`, good luck - but I wouldn't expect most browsers to like that. IIRC an `<a href>` to a ClickOnce ".application" file on a network share used to work, but I haven't tried to do this in years

Comment: yes ClickOnce is still a thing... anyway to launch an executable from a browser, *at least one* actively-confirming user interaction (click) is required. more clicks if the exe is not publisher signed.

Comment: @dlatikay re user clicks required: I would be very concerned if it were not :)  good to know that it is still a thing, though - I just haven't needed those tools lately